# Angular 10 + primeng 4 Radiobutton throwing cannot find nativeElement of undefined error

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, angular10

Page is crashing after migration of angular 9 to 10, so getting an error, cannot find nativeElement of undefined.

Following is the code snippet used:

```
<div>
  <p-radioButton name="group" value="XXX" [(ngModel)]="accType"></p-radioButton>
  <p-radioButton name="group" value="YYY" [(ngModel)]="accType"></p-radioButton>
</div>
```

Attaching screenshot of exception.
[image]

Comment: Facing the same issue in Angular 9 . Did you get a solution for this ?
My question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025998/why-does-usage-of-primeng-p-radiobutton-cause-native-element-error-in-angular-9

Comment: Did you update/downgrade primeNg to Angular ver?