# Can I use Primeng 5 with in angular 10 project?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular10

I am upgrading my angular 5 application to angular 10. I want to continue with the same primeng version ie 5.2.0 .

Comment: Don't see any issues with that, but generally I would recommend you to update your primeng as well, to prevent compatibility issues.

Comment: hi , I think this will not work primeng teem always release new version base of angular version so this is very huge risk  

Comment: something else comparing  primeng 10 with 5 is huge and allot of future you will miss.

Comment: Actually the theme i am using in primeng is not available in primeng 10, Which is creating issues for me. Is there any other way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

primeng 5 has no support now from primeng team and community and **every primeng version update base of angular version** , mean primeng 5 meant to work with angular 5 not perversions of higher version.

some angular api change will give a error can't be solve.

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025998/why-does-usage-of-primeng-p-radiobutton-cause-native-element-error-in-angular-9/65068629#65068629) give some problem when use an old version of primeng.